# Polymorphism/Overriding

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Could someone please explain what the difference is between these two examples?

> ## Class A
>
> `protected virtual string GetData()`
>
> ## Class B
>
> `private override string GetData()`

And the following:

> ## Class A
>
> `protected string GetData()`
>
> ## Class B
>
> `private string GetData()`

Assuming that 'Class B' inherits from 'Class A'.

I always assumed that you need to use `virtual` in the superclass and `override` in the subclass if you want overriding of a method, however I tried removing the keywords and the program compiled fine. What exactly is the difference, if any?

Comment: Do you see the squiggly under B.GetData()?  Do you see the warning in the View + Error List?  Hard to miss, use the *new* keyword when you know what you're doing.

Comment: In the first example B's method can't be private. It won't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example that you showed hides the GetData of the parent, it doesn't override it.

Example:

```
private class Base
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

private class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Base b = new Base();
    Derived d = new Derived();
    Base dInB = new Derived();

    b.Test();
    d.Test();
    dInB.Test();

    b.Test2();
    d.Test2();
    dInB.Test2();

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Base    // Base.Test()
Derived // Derived.Test()
Derived // Derived.Test()
Base    // Base.Test2()
Derived // Derived.Test2()
Base    // You think you're calling Derived.Test2(), but you actually call Base.Test2()
```

Actually this sample is invalid, because it should use the `new` keyword in `public new void Test2()` in the Derived class.

It works just like operator overloading. It doesn't actually override anything. When you have the exact type `Derived` it calls the new method.

**You have to be really careful with hiding members, it is nothing like overriding (classes) or implementing (interfaces) at all. Only when you have the** ***exact*** type it'll call a `new` **method, otherwise it'll still call the base type's method!**

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first case you are overriding and in the second case you are hiding which is completely different.

In the first case:

```
class B: A
{
    void Foo()
    {
        B b = new B();
        A a = b;

        a.GetData() //B's GetData() will be called
        b.GetData() //B's GetData() will be called
    }
}
```

On the other hand in the second case:

```
class B: A
{
    void Foo()
    {
        B b = new B();
        A a = b;

        a.GetData() //A's GetData() will be called
        b.GetData() //B's GetData() will be called
    }
}
```

In the second case you are simply hiding A's implementation of GetData() but you will always be able to call A's implementation through a variable typed A even if the variable refers to a instance of type B. Note that this is completely different from how overriding behaves.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string GetData() { return "A";}
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string GetData() { return "B"; }
}
```

What do you expect if you are using the classes as in the following codeblock?

```
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        A c = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(a.GetData());
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetData());
        Console.WriteLine(c.GetData());
```

This will print "A" "B" "B". The variable c is stored as A type but when executing the method the code is resolved to the "real" implementation. (see google for virtual function table and resolving principle)

If you do not use virtual and override as in the code below  this will print "A" "B" "A".

```
public class A
{
    public string GetData() { return "A";}
}

public class B : A
{
    public new string GetData() { return "B"; }
}
```